# Align five icons into two rows to form a triangle

Tags: html, css

[picture I am trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huurG.png)

[my HTML and CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA2ti.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image, write it in a working snippet here or on sites like Codepen or Jsfiddle.

Comment: please post your code here [link](https://codepen.io/pen/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=56a6a1fbb0efd0cfe42b594aff32006a0ec06fae-1592605704-0-AQE1slSvf0YP-jBf2sJY4yeeHp76AKpkSjuMXQAzvkFeuDlhT-y6IH0HEb9u0bQzzxLJ5kY07824SR-WGh4tivg2jGKQNsbKav1ISqWWbr5rjBAztE5DmvviHgenEw5NZvepMJ0oJanygwG2BDosU238zKATnYNl_413kXj97VHwE9fx_wLsT6Yt_3yIAu3Gn_Io4pKR4Qo756ouXVgoy4ppnU157PtBHqmQ0kudWlH1ULxuKlDQNQaRT1SMu7aGXcmihUX-IjH8ahI8lwKlpoNVBjxlOeuWmPX6GmyMaP7srbOmEVv5kPniOIf6XDMcM7sjt4Fs5TLpYfW4n5zWsi4)

Comment: Also post the code here also, not just in a code tester like codepen or jsfiddle.  The code needs to be here in case the link to external code dies.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nishatill/pen/pogRqaK

Comment: .members-wrapper {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-areas: "1 2 ." "3 4 5";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added html and css code according to your image provided, please have a look.

Try Running this code snippet:

```css
img{
  height: 25px;
  width: auto
}



.members-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
   padding: 20px;
   
}

.members-wrapper > div {
    border: 3px dotted brown;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    flex: 1 1 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 25%;
   
}

.row1, .row2 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center
}

h4 {
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="members-wrapper">
  <div class="team">
    <div class="row1">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img2">
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img3">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img4">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img5">
    </div>
    <h4>Team</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="board">
    <div class="row1">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
    </div>
    <h4>Board</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="mentors">
    <div class="row1">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
    </div>
    <h4>Mentors</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="advisors">
    <div class="row1">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-profile-avatar-man-circle-round-user-30452.png&f=1&nofb=1" class="person img1">
    </div>
    <h4>Advisors</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image source: duckduckgo

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I am new to StackOverFlow. This was my First post.  Cut me some Slack here.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nisha_UX is there anything wrong with my answer. why i got downvote?

Comment: Hi Suraj, I am so sorry.  I unintentionally did that.  And I have no idea how I managed to do it.   I don't see any down or up vote options?  I edit it ... Just trying to figure it out.